# Lazy loading Telerik window content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 3 and using Telerik. I have an empty telerik window. My goal is to only ask server for content when the user clicks a  button, however I have no idea how this could be done. I imagine that to accomplish this I would need to store a reference to the telerik window in question. But how do i do this? plz help. This is how far I have got:

```
@{
   Html.Telerik().Window()
   .Name("ImportDialog")
   .ClientEvents(events => events.OnOpen("DialogOpen"))
   .Visible(false)
   .Title("Import users")
   .Draggable(false)
   .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Enabled(false))
   .Modal(true)
   .Width(400)
   .Height(400)
   .Render();
}
```

I do want do do somethin in DialogOpen function, or alternatevly replace that client side function with a server side funciton....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the client API of the Telerik Window and more specifically the [ajaxRequest](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-window-client-api-and-events.html#ajaxRequest) method.

So for example when the button is clicked you should get the client object and call the ajaxRequest method which will make the Window retrieve its content from that MVC action method.
e.g.

```
function DialogOpen(){
    var myWin= $('#ImportDialog').data('tWindow');
    myWin.ajaxRequest("Controller/Action", { name: "John",location:"Boston"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one type of answer, however i am not sure yet if it is the best.

In the javascript function DialogOpen I send an ajax request to an url(also known as an Action of a Controller in MVC), the I put the result in the content of the dialog window, like so:

```
function DialogOpen () 
{
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Controller/Action",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function (htmlContent) 
    {
        $('#ImportDialogContent').html(htmlContent);
    },
    error: function () 
    {
        $('#ImportDialogContent').html("<p>Could not import user data at this time</p>");
    }
 });
}
```

P.S.: I gave an ID to content area of telerik Window(ImportDialogContent)!